# Need help with long forms using Solspace Freeform Pro

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I've set up normal forms using Freeform, but now we have a client who has these massively long forms that require something I've never done before.

Currently all the forms are built with Google Forms, which provides a way for whoever is filling out the form to stop, submit the form so far, and come back later to continue.

Solspace support assures me this has been done with Freeform Pro. Does anyone have any ideas or code examples that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you considered using multipage forms? http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#multipage This however assumes the user will go through the whole multipage form in one sitting. Did users need to stop midway, and come back to the form much later to fill out the rest?

Comment: Yes, when rebuilding the forms with Freeform, I would absolutely use a multi-page form. But users would still need to be able to stop midway and come back later. It would be mostly secretaries that would be filling out the forms, and constant inturruptions are unfortunately part of the job.

Comment: When I say "later", I mean are you looking for a way to fill out a form, save it, and return to edit it some more later. In that case you could use a 1-page form, and save it as "pending" with what you could fill out. Then, use `{exp:freeform:edit}` to reopen the Freeform entry and make edits to it. Once completely done and happy with the form, change the status to "open" and submit.

Comment: Yes, saving it as "pending" with the option of returning later to finish. We'd be asking thousands of organizations to use this system. How would they be able to tell which form was theirs? Other systems I've seen use an entry id in the url to make this distinction (/form/edit/2514). I don't want to go just by an entry id, as that would make it extremely easy to edit another organization's form by just offsetting the url. Google Forms employs an encrypted link that you use to edit your form. Is that an option here?

Comment: You can restrict editing powers to a form by using `restrict_edit_to_author="yes"`. http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/edit/#restrict_edit_to_author

Comment: Let me see if I'm following your train of thought. Lock the form behind a login. The author can then log in and either fill out a new form or see links to any forms they have authored that have a pending status. That way we would use the freeform:edit template structure with editing restricted to the author. Once the status is "open" any confirmation messages would be sent.Would the user have the option to change the status to "open" once they were done with their edits, or would that have to be done by an admin? If the user can change the form status themselves, I think this would work!

Comment: You got it right. Also, users can change the status to "open" themselves. Make sure to add the `allow_status_edit="yes"` parameter.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for your help!